# Android wear project not getting compiled with gradle upgrade

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I upgrade my Gradle to 2.1 and project started giving this error.

```
Error:Could not initialize class sun.management.ManagementFactoryHelper
```

Can anyone help me on this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution. Firstly I cleared and rebuild the project then restarted android studio using "File --> Invalid cache/Restart" option.

Then after restarting studio gradle ask for fix some requirements. Which downloaded by studio And application started normally.

Cheers...!!!